# Haystack scores make no sense

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using haystack with elastic search for a project, but the scores I get make no sense (to me).

The model I'm trying to index and search looks similar to:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Color(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And the search index, even if I'm interested in cars, I want to search them by color as I want to display a pic of that color specifically:

```py
class CarIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Color

    def prepare_text(self, obj):
        # Some cleaning
        return " ".join([obj.name, obj.car.name])
```

Now I add a car with three colors, a LaFerrari in Red, Black and White. Having only one model of car, for search purposes there are 3 cars.

So I check Kibana and I get a normal output.

[image: kibana empty]

Then I perform a normal search: LaFerrari

[image: kibana weird score]

All three models have the same info, changing only the color name on the text field. I've even tried removing the color from the text, and guess what I got.

[image: kibana weird 2]

After this fiasco, I tried the python elasticsearch library, and I got normal results (doing manual index and search), all three colors had the same score if I performed a search for `LaFerrari`.

Any idea what is going on?

I'm thinking about moving from haystack to plain elasticsearch, any recommendations?

Comment: Is this a typo? `def get_model(self): return Color` - shouldn't this read `return Car`?

Comment: @Risadinha It's not a typo, I want to index by Color, It's a bit confusing, but for the search model I want, works.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that what you call `Color` is a `Car` and what you call `Car` is something like a `Brand`. On top of that, you name the index `CarIndex` which makes it even more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search more distinctively you should add two more fields to the index:

- color (and this is really the color like `white` however you name the models and attributes)
- name (the brand name)

The catch-all document field will get you only so far. You would have to make it so that Elasticsearch uses a DisMax query and searches on all configured fields for the given search terms.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html

I've only used the `SearchQuerySet`+Elastic (based on the catch-all field) so far (and custom+Solr a lot). While the `SearchQuerySet` fits in very nicely with the Django ORM it will only get you so far. So, you are probably right that you might have to use custom code for querying. I would still recommend Haystack for indexing though (it might be slower but very easy to setup and maintain).

Looking at your example, what you gain with different fields would be:

You search for `Laferrari` and this is the exact value found in all three documents in the field `name` (or `brand_name`). The results will then have the same scores.

Different fields also enable you to use facets: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-facets.html#search-facets